# Google Analytics Referrer issue in android

Tags: android, url, google-analytics, analytics, referrer

I've been having some trouble getting my referrer tracking to work with GA (Google Analytics) in my Android app. There isn't much info in the GA Doc. I am only using GA to track the referrer, by the way. Nothing else.

In my manifest file i have exactly this within the application tags:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

I have then created a URL using the generator, tested it but still no stats are showing at all.

There was nothing else in the docs. Nothing to link this referral to my GA account, which I think is very strange. Is there something in my Activity that I have to write to send the referrer information to my GA account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add to your Activity:

```
    GoogleAnalyticsTracker GATracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
    GATracker.start("UA-XXXXXX-XX",20, this);

    GATracker.trackPageView("Page-to-track");
```

Refer this for complete setting: [Google Analytics SDK for Android](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/)

Comment: Even though is wasn't covered in the referrer section of the docs, I already had the first two lines of what you posted. I didn't put in trackPageView() as I just want to track the referrer. Thanks for your help anyways. (Edited for clarification)

Comment: It turns out that the Google Doc assumes that you are using Google Analytics to track everything else in your app and doesn't mention that the referrer information gets sent when you log an event or track a page view. Thanks for your help